# How do I show distinct values from one column along with one of it's corresponding rows?

Tags: postgresql

How can I show distinct values from one column, and show one of the values from another column on the same row?  This is probably easiest to explain with example outputs, shown below.

The query should only return the same number of rows as there are distinct values in the `permission` column, in this case, two.

Where the `permission` column has `select`, that row will either show `Alice` or `Bob` in the `username` column.  Where the `permission` column has `insert`, that row will either show `Carol`, `Alice`, `Bob`, or `David` in the `username` column.

It's okay if different `username`s are returned each time.  Performance is not a critical factor - there will be a less than a few dozen rows per table.

users_and_permissions table

| username | permission |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | select |
| Bob | select |
| Carol | insert |
| Alice | insert |
| Bob | insert |
| David | insert |

Output #1

| username | permission |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | select |
| Carol | insert |

Output #2

| username | permission |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | select |
| Bob | insert |

Output #3

| username | permission |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | select |
| David | insert |

Output #4

| username | permission |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | select |
| David | insert |

Edit: I deleted my SQL from the original post because it was using two tables and a join with a DISTINCT ON clause.

Comment: have you tried using DISTINCT ON ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis Yes - that clause is part of my question.

Comment: Please explain the logic, without using SQL, at how you arrive at  each output. I.E. Explain why output #2 contains Bob/Bob but output #3 contains Bob/David. Like wise output #1 vs output #4 Alice/Carol vs Alice/David.

Comment: @Belayer Good suggestion.  I revised (and simplified, hopefully!) my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out DISTINCT clause at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html

```sql
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (permission)
  username,
  permission
FROM
  users_and_permissions
ORDER BY 
  permission;
```

If you want control of the usernames that are displayed - use `ORDER BY` at the end of the statement.